# Can i put 2 arrays in each loop with AJAX?

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax

I need to work with 2 JSON Object arrays, is it possible to put both arrays in same each loop  with && separator or instead each inside each?

I need to work with 2 arrays in same loop, how can it be possible?

This is my JSON from php page:

```
function loadBlocSite() {
    //Création d'un tableau
    $currentArrayData = array();

    //Remplissage du tableau    
    $currentArrayData['configAlm'] = array(
                            array('blocName' => 'blockAlarmeContent',     'blocLVTwoName' => 'boxLV2Content', 'blocHeader' => 'ALARME',      'label' => 'Criticité',            'id' => 'almCrit',         'ico' => '', 'refreshFreq' => '2', 'TNT' => '2', 'FM' => '2'),
                            array('blocName' => 'blockAlarmeContent',    'blocLVTwoName' => 'boxLV2Content', 'blocHeader' => 'ALARME',    'label' => 'Sans supervision',  'id' => 'almSansSup',     'ico' => '', 'refreshFreq' => '2', 'TNT' => '2', 'FM' => '2'),
                            array('blocName' => 'blockAlarmeContent',    'blocLVTwoName' => 'boxLV2Content',    'blocHeader' => 'ALARME',    'label' => 'Non nominale',        'id' => 'almNonNom',     'ico' => '', 'refreshFreq' => '2', 'TNT' => '2', 'FM' => '2')
    );
    $currentArrayData['configSite'] = array(
                            array('blocName' => 'blockSitesContent',    'blocLVTwoName' => 'boxLV2Content', 'blocHeader' => 'ALARME',    'label' => '-3dB',            'id' => 'steMoins3db',     'ico' => '', 'refreshFreq' => '2', 'TNT' => '4', 'FM' => '1'),
                            array('blocName' => 'blockSitesContent',    'blocLVTwoName' => 'boxLV2Content', 'blocHeader' => 'ALARME',    'label' => 'Rx',              'id' => 'steRx',         'ico' => '', 'refreshFreq' => '2', 'TNT' => '4', 'FM' => '1'),
                            array('blocName' => 'blockSitesContent',    'blocLVTwoName' => 'boxLV2Content',    'blocHeader' => 'ALARME',    'label' => 'Perte HF',        'id' => 'stePerteHF',     'ico' => '', 'refreshFreq' => '2', 'TNT' => '4', 'FM' => '1'),
                            array('blocName' => 'blockSitesContent',    'blocLVTwoName' => 'boxLV2Content',    'blocHeader' => 'ALARME',    'label' => 'Décrochage HS',    'id' => 'steDecrochHS', 'ico' => '', 'refreshFreq' => '2', 'TNT' => '4', 'FM' => '1'),
                            // array (
                            // array('blocName' => 'blockSitesContent',    'label' => 'GE Actif En cours', 'id' => 'steGEEnCours',     'ico' => '', 'refreshFreq' => '2', 'val' => '2'),
                            // array('blocName' => 'blockSitesContent',    'label' => 'GE Actif -10 jrs',    'id' => 'steGEMoins10jrs',     'ico' => '', 'refreshFreq' => '2', 'val' => '2')
                            // );
    );
    return $currentArrayData;
}
```

here is my code :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Pages/index.php', //ou il y a le traitement json
    type:  'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: 'action=loadBlocSite',
    success:function(data){

        $.each(arrayOfData['configAlm'], function(currentIdx, currentValue){
            $.each(arrayOfData['configsite'], function(currentIdx, currentValue){
                if(currentValue.id == "almCrit"){
                    $("#almCrit").click(function() {
                        $('#mainViewContainer').animate({'left': '-30rem'}, 250, function(){
                            $('#boxLV2Content').empty();
                            var criticiteContent = '';
                            criticiteContent += '<div class="tableHeader">';
                            criticiteContent += '<div class="tableCell_title">TNT</div>';
                            criticiteContent += '<div class="tableCell_title">FM</div>';
                            criticiteContent += '</div>';
                            criticiteContent += '<div class="lineBloc">';
                            criticiteContent += '<img class="lineBlocIco" src="'+ currentValue.ico +'">';
                            criticiteContent += '<div class="lineBlocTitle">'+ currentValue.label +'</div>';
                            criticiteContent += '<div class="lineBlocValue">'+ currentValue.TNT +'</div>';
                            criticiteContent += '<div class="lineBlocValue">'+ currentValue.FM +'</div>';
                            criticiteContent += '</div>';
                            console.log(currentValue.blocName);
                            $("#" + currentValue.blocLVTwoName).append(criticiteContent);
                        });
                    });
                } else return 'this is not almCrit Id';
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Are both arrays just as long, and do values belong together when they are at the same index in both arrays? You have not really explained how these two arrays are connected, and your code obviously is only seeing the `currentValue` declared in the inner loop, repeating the same thing several times because of the outer loop. For example, is `ico` a property of the first or the second array's object? Please provide sample input and desired output for that input.

Comment: where is ajax here?

Comment: @Hitmands i just apdated my post for ajax call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to overwrite your vars.. You need to change your code to

```
$.each(arrayOfData['configAlm'], function(currentIdx, currentValue){
    $.each(arrayOfData['configsite'], function(_currentIdx, _currentValue){...
```

Be aware that you are going to loop the 2nd array every time you cycle through the first one ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to use nested each loops, however, you need to use different parameter names or else the inner loop will overwrite the outer loop. This will iterate over the inner object for each element in the outer object, so i'm not sure that is the behavior you are looking for, but to do that you could do this

```
$.each(arrayOfData['configAlm'], function(currentIdx, currentValue){
    $.each(arrayOfData['configsite'], function(currentIdx2, currentValue2){...
```

Comment: did you change the inner part of your loop to reflect the changes here?

Comment: yes i change it exactly as you mentionned in my code but not here in the question..it doesn't give me any error it just doesn't work

Comment: what elements in your inner loop reference each array